# Laravel paginate comments

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-blade

I'm trying to "remove" the thread of my application when the pagination is used.

So I have a thread and the URL to that tread is `http://localhost/rebelbb/Thread-test`. When I want to Go to paginate so `http://localhost/rebelbb/Thread-test?page=2` Then It needs to hide the thread. What I got now:

```
@if(Request::url() == Config::get('app.url').'/Thread-'.$threads->title)
```

But that doesn't work...

So anyone who has an tip?

How am I be able to hide the topic when the URL isn't 
`http://localhost/rebelbb/Thread-test` or `http://localhost/rebelbb/Thread-test?page=1` ?

Comment: How are you fetching the data from the database?

Comment: Just like this: http://laravel.io/bin/jQlak

Comment: I don't see you paginating threads there, just comments. Could you elaborate on what you need? You want to hide a thread with specific id when there is page parameter in the URL? Or hide specific comment? Your question doesn't make it clear

Comment: I want to hide the thread when the pagination gos to page 2/3/4/... So right now, the thread doesn't hide and stays at the top of the page like on page 1.

Comment: Have a look at my answer and let me know if that's what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the view if there is **page** parameter set by using:

```
@if(Request::has('page'))
```

or you can check if the page is not the first one by doing:

```
@if(Request::get('page', 1) != 1)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks, Coulden't get the if statement right. the code I needed to use was `@if(Request::get('page', 1) == 1)` :) Thank you!